# How to validate captcha in registration form?

Tags: php, captcha

I'm trying to create a registration form with a captcha, using [this tutorial](http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/html-contact-form-captcha.html), but I don't know how to validate the captcha, can you help me?

```
<?php

include ('php/mysql_prisijungimas.php');


if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {
    $error = array();//Declare An Array to store any error message  
    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {//if no name has been supplied 
        $error[] = 'Please Enter a name ';//add to array "error"
    } else {
        $name = $_POST['name'];//else assign it a variable
    }

    if (empty($_POST['e-mail'])) {
        $error[] = 'Please Enter your Email ';
    } else {


        if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST['e-mail'])) {
           //regular expression for email validation
            $Email = $_POST['e-mail'];
        } else {
             $error[] = 'Your EMail Address is invalid  ';
        }


    }


    if (empty($_POST['Password'])) {
        $error[] = 'Please Enter Your Password ';
    } else {
        $Password = $_POST['Password'];
    }


    if (empty($error)) //send to Database if there's no error '

    { // If everything's OK...

        // Make sure the email address is available:
        $query_verify_email = "SELECT * FROM members  WHERE Email ='$Email'";
        $result_verify_email = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_verify_email);
        if (!$result_verify_email) {//if the Query Failed ,similar to if($result_verify_email==false)
            echo ' Database Error Occured ';
        }

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result_verify_email) == 0) { // IF no previous user is using this email .


            // Create a unique  activation code:
            $activation = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));


            $query_insert_user = "INSERT INTO `members` ( `Username`, `Email`, `Password`, `Activation`) VALUES ( '$name', '$Email', '$Password', '$activation')";


            $result_insert_user = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_insert_user);
            if (!$result_insert_user) {
                echo 'Query Failed ';
            }

            if (md5($_POST['norobot']) == $_SESSION['randomnr2'])   { 
        // here you  place code to be executed if the captcha test passes
            echo "Hey great , it appears you are not a robot";
    }   else {  
        // here you  place code to be executed if the captcha test fails
            echo "you're a very naughty robot!";
    }

            if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) { //If the Insert Query was successfull.


                // Send the email:
                $message = " To activate your account, please click on this link:\n\n";
                $message .= WEBSITE_URL . '/activate.php?email=' . urlencode($Email) . "&key=$activation";
                mail($Email, 'Registration Confirmation', $message, 'From: test@gmail.com');

                // Flush the buffered output.


                // Finish the page:
                echo '<div class="success">Thank you for
registering! A confirmation email
has been sent to '.$Email.' Please click on the Activation Link to Activate your account </div>';


            } else { // If it did not run OK.
                echo '<div class="errormsgbox">You could not be registered due to a system
error. We apologize for any
inconvenience.</div>';
            }

        } else { // The email address is not available.
            echo '<div class="errormsgbox" >That email
address has already been registered.
</div>';
        }

    } else {//If the "error" array contains error msg , display them



echo '<div class="errormsgbox"> <ol>';
        foreach ($error as $key => $values) {

            echo '  <li>'.$values.'</li>';



        }
        echo '</ol></div>';

    }

    mysqli_close($dbc);//Close the DB Connection

} // End of the main Submit conditional.



?>


<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <!-- Remove this line if you use the .htaccess -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <meta name="description" content="test.">
    <meta name="author" content="test">

    <title>test</title>


    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stilius.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<hr>
<div class="home-page main">
    <section class="grid-wrap" >
        <header class="grid col-full">

<div class="right">
<form align="center" action="registracija.php" method="post" class="registration_form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Registracijos forma </legend>


    <div class="elements">
      <label for="name">Slapyvardis :</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="25" />
    </div>
    <div class="elements">
      <label for="e-mail">El. pa&#353;tas :</label>
      <input type="text" id="e-mail" name="e-mail" size="25" />
    </div>
    <div class="elements">
      <label for="Password">slapta&#382;odis:</label>
      <input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" size="25" />


      <img src="captcha_code_file.php?rand=<?php echo rand(); ?>"
id="captchaimg" >
<label for="message">Enter the code above here :</label>
<input id="6_letters_code" name="6_letters_code" type="text">



    </div>
    <div class="submit">
     <input type="hidden" name="formsubmitted" value="TRUE" />
      <input type="submit" value="Registruotis!" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is my all time fav here [Google CAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php)

Answer (score 2):

Captcha is just any string created using image library.Process as below:

1- create random or dictionary word string
2- store it anywhere [session in your case before displaying your registration form
3- compare session value to user submit value

Your code :

```
if (md5($_POST['norobot']) == $_SESSION['randomnr2'])
{
    echo 'You passed captcha test';
}
```

$_SESSION['randomnr2'] is random string created and stored in session.before storing it is md5 encrypted.

Comment: I put it in code, but now it says "The captcha code does not match!" even if I write right captcha, I was using this tutorial http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/html-contact-form-captcha.html

Comment: //try to 
print md5($_POST['norobot']);
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_SESSION);